# How to make calculation of fields from different Django Models? (JOIN)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

There are now three tables:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

class HistoricalData(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    demand_sold = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class ForecastData(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    demand_sold = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I need to compare Historical and Forecast data for the list of products and calculate the accuracy rate. Formula like: `ForecastData.demand_sold * 100/HistoricalData.demand_sold`
The current solution is to iterate through the history and forecast datasets and make calculations for `demand_sold`

```
products = Product.objects.filter(...)
queryset_hist = HistoricalData.objects.filter(product__in=products)
queryset_forecast = ForecastData.objects.filter(product__in=products)
```

I am wondering is there any elegant solution to calculate field from different Django Models. (For example Join?)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
products = Product.objects.all()
for p in products:  # p is an object of class Product
    one_historical_record = HistoricalData.objects.filter(product=p)
    one_forecast_record = ForecastData.objects.filter(product=p)
    forecast_for_product_p = one_forecast_record.demand_sold * 100/one_historical_record.demand_sold
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yep, currently, this is my solution. The problem is I have thousands of products.In the example you attached Django will query DB each iteration. I would like to reduce queries to DB. So I am looking how to optimize my solution and make calculation for example on DB side.

Comment: You could probably use annotate then:

`products = Products.objects.filter(...).annotate(forecast=F('related_name_forecast__demand_sold') * 100/F('related_name_historical__demand_sold'))`

I think all you would need to do is update HistoricalData and ForecastData models.ForeignKey fields with a `related_name` field to make pulling the reverse query easier.
Like:
`class ForecastData(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="forecast_product")`

(I'm not 100% on the syntax to pull demand_sold through the ForeignKey)

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/

Comment: it still needs to iterate through the whole list of products,which is not OK. I belive there is an option somehow JOIN/merge two tables, and make calculation with the help of DB